# What is opaqueRect used for in XAML popup template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to understand the meaning of each part of controls in the XAML popup templates.
Here is the original code:

```
    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
        AllowsTransparency="true"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
        PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}"
        Placement="Bottom">
    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow"
                                    Color="Transparent"
                                    MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                    MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
        <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder"
                BorderBrush="#FFEBEBEB"
                BorderThickness="1"
                CornerRadius="8"
                Background="White">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer"
                                Template="{StaticResource UniversalScrollViewerTemplate}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid"
                            RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Canvas x:Name="canvas"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Height="0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Width="0">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect"
                                        Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"
                                        Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"
                                        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" />
                        </Canvas>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
</Popup>
```

I'm wondering what's the role of the Canvas Control `canvas` in the `DropDownScrollViewer` -> `grid` since its height and width are both 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `Grid` allows ClearType text rendering. ClearType text has to be rendered to an opaque background.

> Set the `ClearTypeHint` property to `Enabled` to indicate that a subtree is safe for ClearType text rendering. **Do this only when you can be certain that the text is rendering to a fully opaque background**.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.cleartypehint(v=vs.110).aspx